# clicking multiple buttons reveals div tag

Tags: jquery, button

I'd like to be able to click a series of buttons, and once all are clicked reveal a div tag element. I've tried a couple of other threads on here, but not been successful and getting the code to work. any help would be gratefully accepted. If this was flash I'd have done it fine. #learningnewskills

```
<button class="w3-button" onclick="plusDivs">one of five</button>
<button class="w3-button" onclick="plusDivs">two of five</button>
<button class="w3-button" onclick="plusDivs">three of five</button>
<button class="w3-button" onclick="plusDivs">four of five</button>
<button class="w3-button" onclick="plusDivs">five of five</button>

The following div tag is hidden by default and revealed when all five buttons are clicked...

<div class="hidden-until-all-clicked">You clicked all five buttons</div>
```

Comment: You are going to need to add some javascript/jQuery to this...

Comment: Thankfully Flash is (almost...) dead; I'm afraid you need to learn JavaScript. Break your task into individual steps in pseudo code, research each step and when, or *if*, you have problems with your implementation then come and ask us about those problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using jQuery:

```
$('.w3-button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');

    // Check to see if all the .w3-button elements are 'clicked'
    if ($('.w3-button:not(".clicked")').length == 0) {
        $('.hidden-until-all-clicked').show();
    }
});
```

Hope this works for you.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

You have to save in a variable the number of clicks per element

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("w3-button"),
    hidden = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-until-all-clicked")[0],
    len = button.length,
    count = 0,
    i;
function click(){
  count += 1;
  if(count == len){
    hidden.style.display="block";
  }
  this.removeEventListener("click", click);
}
for(i=0;i<len;i+=1){
  button[i].addEventListener("click", click);
}
```

```css
.hidden-until-all-clicked{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="w3-button">one of five</button>
<button class="w3-button">two of five</button>
<button class="w3-button">three of five</button>
<button class="w3-button">four of five</button>
<button class="w3-button">five of five</button>

<p>The following div tag is hidden by default and revealed when all five buttons are clicked...</p>

<div class="hidden-until-all-clicked">You clicked all five buttons</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $("#" + i + "b").click(function() {
    if ($("#" + this.id).attr('class') != "noclick") {
      sum++;
      $("#" + this.id).attr('class', 'noclick');
    }
    if (sum == 5) {
      $("#hid").show();
    }
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qnb058k5/